# PHP MySQL newest records from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select the latest 10 records from multiple tables (ORDER BY date). For example, 8 of the newest records might be in one table and 2 in another (10 rows in total). Is there a way to select those 10 records?

Comment: What exactly your table structure is?

Comment: Unless you have a date/updated field, or the IDs are somehow magically common across tables, not really.

Comment: do u have a date column in the table?

Comment: I can add a date column @Fluffeh

Comment: Please post your table structure or create a sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM
     ( SELECT * FROM x
       UNION ALL
       SELECT * FROM y
     ) n
 ORDER 
    BY date DESC 
 LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use:

```
SELECT column_name(s) 
FROM table1 
ORDER BY date LIMIT 0,8
UNION ALL
SELECT column_name(s) 
FROM table2 
ORDER BY date LIMIT 0,2;
```

Comment: mysql with `top` no way !!

Comment: My bad. i have changed it to limi.

Comment: If this is the answer, then the question was *extremely* misleading. I suspect that this is not the answer!

Comment: @Strawberry I see what you mean. He thinks I need 8 rows from one table and 2 from another but that was just an example

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT some_data AS alias1, date_field AS mydate
   FROM table1
UNION ALL
    SELECT datazzz AS alias1, another_datefield AS mydate
    FROM table2
) 
ORDER BY mydate DESC LIMIT 10
```

Syntax might need a little bit of tweaking, but that's the gist of it.

Specifically, you need to select whatever data you want out of each of the tables and then use aliases to make sure they have the same column names (otherwise they can't be returned in the same result set). Then after that you need to order by the common date field.

Comment: "otherwise they can't be returned in the same result set" eh? You need the same number of columns and, properly, the same data types/collations. That's all.

Comment: @Strawberry Oh? I thought the names needed to be the same too.